# DataContractSerializer on mono returns weird errors

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, datacontractserializer

I have made a simple data serializer to just serialize my data on it, There's so simple ways to serialize and deserialize the data, I got two ways to do that:

```
public string Serialize()
    {
        SerializedData data = new SerializedData(this);
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SerializedData));
        System.IO.MemoryStream s = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        serializer.WriteObject(s, data);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(s.ToArray());
    }

    public static MessageBlock Deserialize(string name, string sdata, Map map)
    {
        byte[] bdata = Convert.FromBase64String(sdata);
        MessageBlock MessageBlock = new MessageBlock();
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SerializedData));
        System.IO.MemoryStream s = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bdata);
        SerializedData data = (SerializedData)serializer.ReadObject(s);

        data.UpdateMessageBlock(MessageBlock);
        return MessageBlock;
    }
    [DataContract]
    private class SerializedData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public String Name;
        [DataMember]
        public String Creator;
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime Created;
        [DataMember]
        public String World;
        [DataMember]
        public Vector3I AffectedBlock;
        [DataMember]
        public int XMin;
        [DataMember]
        public int XMax;
        [DataMember]
        public int YMin;
        [DataMember]
        public int YMax;
        [DataMember]
        public int ZMin;
        [DataMember]
        public int ZMax;
        [DataMember]
        public String Message;

        public SerializedData(MessageBlock MessageBlock)
        {
            lock (MessageBlock)
            {
                Name = MessageBlock.Name;
                Creator = MessageBlock.Creator;
                Created = MessageBlock.Created;
                World = MessageBlock.World;
                AffectedBlock = MessageBlock.AffectedBlock;
                XMin = MessageBlock.Range.Xmin;
                XMax = MessageBlock.Range.Xmax;
                YMin = MessageBlock.Range.Ymin;
                YMax = MessageBlock.Range.Ymax;
                ZMin = MessageBlock.Range.Zmin;
                ZMax = MessageBlock.Range.Zmax;
                Message = MessageBlock.Message;
            }
        }

        public void UpdateMessageBlock(MessageBlock MessageBlock)
        {
            MessageBlock.Name = Name;
            MessageBlock.Creator = Creator;
            MessageBlock.Created = Created;
            MessageBlock.World = World;
            MessageBlock.AffectedBlock = AffectedBlock;
            MessageBlock.Range = new MessageBlockRange(XMin, XMax, YMin, YMax, ZMin, ZMax);
            MessageBlock.Message = Message;
        }
    }
```

Server i run code on it is ubuntu using mono 3.2.1, There's no problem for windows, I can run codes easily without any error on windows NET 4, But it seems like mono doesn't support DataContractSerializer, The error i get on mono is:

`09:04:19 > ERROR: Map failed to save: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Circular reference of an object in the object graph was found: '(0,0,-1)' of type fCraft.Vector3I
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationMap.Serialize (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer.Serialize (System.Type type, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationMap.SerializeNonReference (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationMap.Serialize (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer.Serialize (System.Type type, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationMap.SerializeNonReference (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationMap.Serialize (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer.Serialize (System.Type type, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationMap.SerializeNonReference (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationMap.Serialize (System.Object graph, System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer serializer) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer.Serialize (System.Type type, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlFormatterSerializer.Serialize (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph, System.Type declaredType, System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeCollection types, Boolean ignoreUnknown, Int32 maxItems, System.String root_ns, Boolean preserveObjectReferences, System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver resolver, System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractResolver defaultResolver) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObjectContent (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlDictionaryWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.WriteObject (System.Xml.XmlWriter writer, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.WriteObject (System.IO.Stream stream, System.Object graph) [0x00000] in :0
  at fCraft.MessageBlock.Serialize () [0x00000] in :0
  at fCraft.MessageBlockSerialization.Serialize (fCraft.Map map, System.IO.Stream stream, IMapConverterEx converter) [0x00000] in :0
  at fCraft.MapConversion.MapFCMv3+<>c_DisplayClass4.b_2 (IConverterExtension ex) [0x00000] in :0
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum[IConverterExtension] (IEnumerable1 source, System.Func2 selector) [0x00000] in :0
  at fCraft.MapConversion.MapFCMv3.WriteMetadata (System.IO.Stream stream, fCraft.Map map) [0x00000] in :0
  at fCraft.MapConversion.MapFCMv3.Save (fCraft.Map mapToSave, System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0
  at fCraft.MapConversion.MapUtility.TrySave (fCraft.Map mapToSave, System.String fileName, MapFormat format) [0x00000] in :0
09:04:19 > Warning: Logger.SubmitCrashReport: System.UriFormatException: Uri is longer than the maximum 32766 characters.
  at System.Uri.EscapeDataString (System.String stringToEscape) [0x00000] in :0
  at fCraft.Logger.LogAndReportCrashInner (System.String message, System.String assembly, System.Exception exception) [0x00000] in :0`

Comment: is this code running under an ASP.NET app? if yes, post what `xsp --version` gives

Comment: @knocte No, code is on NET 4.0 Console App.

Comment: mono does support DataContractSerializer, but you've found a bug wrt circular references, please file it here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/